# Warning deprecated conversion from string constant to char *

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I use the cmd to compile with a .bat and g++.exe. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I am using it to practice as I follow a tutorial on strings and arrays. Please keep in mind that I am still learning.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:12: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-
Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:10:12: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [
-Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:11:12: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [
-Wwrite-strings]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My Code:

```
      using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main() {
//Asterisk to make the variable an array. Takes 8 bytes of memory (8 characters including spaces).
 char *a = "hi there";
//Inside square brackets is the number of bytes of memory to use. More consumtion of resources
 char b[500]="hi there";
 //For a new line, type \n. For a tab, type \t.
 char *c = "Hi There\nFriends!";
 char *d = "\t\tHi There Friends!";
 //endl will end the line.
 cout << a;
 cout << b << endl;
 cout << c << endl;
 cout << d << endl;
}
```

Comment: String literals are not modifiable and your types should reflect them as such.

Comment: @chris Extraneous "them" =P

Comment: @WhozCraig, ..., and your types should not reflect the string literals as such. That's what I meant. I assumed "them" was a reasonable placeholder, but it is a bit of an awkward sentence.

Comment: @chris agreed (on both form and reason).

Answer (score 7):

Strings between double quotes are string literals. They are arrays of `char` which are not to be modified (attempting to modify them invokes undefined behavior). That's why you should declare a pointer pointing to a string literal as `const char *` - this way, if some code erroneously tries to write/modify a character in the literal, the compiler will have a chance to catch this error.

Comment: Thank you, and I apologise for the duplicate post.